# How could I determine the most important smallest subset of my independent variables in multivariable linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

First of all I have to say that, My knowledge about statistics limited. I'm trying to learn the topic currently.

I have a high dimensional data. Formally:

I have 7000 points in which all independent variables are 1000 dimensional and I have single dependent variable. I mean, here is the function I've tried to predict coefficients of it.

```
y = w1 * x1 + w2*x2 + ....... + w1000 *x1000
```

By the help of regression, I believe I've found a line that has 0.98 `R^2` value.As you see, the number of independent variable is a lot. (1000). So, I want to find the most important `Xs` (and smallest subset if possible) that gives me the same or almost equal r^2.

My question : What should I do to find the answer ?

Thanks in advance, sorry about the english, its not my natural language.

Comment: This is a good topic.  So good, in fact, that versions of it have now been discussed in several thousand posts on this site.  Please review some of them (many can be found by [a search for "variable selection"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variable+selection)).  If you don't find enough guidance, return here and edit your post to include more context and details to narrow it down.

Comment: @whuber thank you so much for kindly guidance! I'll definitely look the reference.

Answer (score 1):

LASSO is a good way to do this. It's commonly used, and there are many packages/libraries implementing it.

> [Tibshirani (1996)](http://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc2515-2006/readings/lasso.pdf) Regression Shrinkage and Selection via the Lasso

This approach penalizes the $l_1$ norm of the weights, which induces a sparse solution. The weights for many variables are forced to zero, while the weights of the most 'relevant' variables remain nonzero.

Say the dependent variable is represented as a column vector $y$ and the independent variables are represented as columns of matrix $X$ (each row corresponds to a data point). The goal is to find a weight vector $w$ that solves the following optimization problem:

$$\underset{w}{\min} \|y - Xw\|_2^2 + \lambda \|w\|_1$$

$\lambda$ is a hyperparameter that controls the penalty on the $l_1$ norm of the weights. This controls the sparsity of the solution (i.e. the number of selected variables). It's not useful to talk about the smallest subset of predictors by itself (because it's trivially the empty set). Instead, the number of predictors has to be traded off against the accuracy of the model. This is done by setting $\lambda$.

Cross validation is a common approach, which seeks to maximize generalization performance (i.e. predictive performance on new data drawn from the same distribution as the training data). Here, the data is repeatedly split into two disjoint subsets: the training set and the validation set. The weights are fit using the training set, for multiple values of $\lambda$. The error for each model is computed using the validation set, and $\lambda$ is chosen to minimize this error.

Alternatively, if you know a priori that you want a fixed number of predictors, you can find a value of $\lambda$ that yields this number of non-zero weights.

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I wonder whether you provide a complete example or not ?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html